# Quill Wrap Blot value with a child Blot

Tags: javascript, typescript, quill

I want to default all text to using a font-style of Arial and a font-size of 12px.

If I set those as the default for the toolbar, the toolbar UI does not change to a color to indicate that is what you are on (For example, if I place my cursor in some text that is styled to be 15px and Geneva, the UI for the font and size picker will be blue. But if I default the UI to 15 and Geneva, then whenever i place my cursor in some text styled that way, it will just switch to it, but the UI will not have that highlight color).

To get around this, I just opt to not set a default. Which works great, except when I am reading in some legacy values from the database.
These legacy values would look something like this,

```
<p> This is legacy text </p>
```

And should be defaulted to a font-style of Arial and a size of 12px.

So, ideally, I'd like Quill to convert it into:

```
<p>
  <span class="ql-font-arial" style="font-size: 12px;">This is legacy text.</span>
</p>
```

But I cannot get Quill to accept a child node when creating the blot. If I append a child, it gets optimized out because that child will have no content. If I add a child and return a child node, the parent node is never acknowledged by Quill and does not appear in the styling (and puts everything on the same line because it's just one giant optimized `span` tag now.)

Is there any way to get the blot to use format itself to have a child and stick the data into the child?
This is what I'm using right now to capture

tags and keep any alignment formatting they might have. 
But I can't figure out how to have it default it's data to be wrapped in a child `<span>` tag.

```
const BlockBlot = Quill.import('blots/block');

export class PBlot extends BlockBlot {
  static create(data: { alignment: string }) {
    let node: Element = document.createElement('P');
    if (data && data.alignment) {
      node.setAttribute('class', `ql-align-${data.alignment.toLowerCase()}`);
    }
    let sNode = document.createElement('SPAN');
    node.appendChild(sNode);
    //return sNode;
    return node;
  }

  static formats(node: Element) {
    return { alignment: node.getAttribute('align') || undefined };
  }
}
PBlot.tagName = 'P';
PBlot.blotName = 'block';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `const BlockEmbed = Quill.import('blots/block/embed');` instead.
Changing `tagName` to `<div>` might work as well.

Comment: This absolutely worked for me.  I wanted to be able to wrap multiple child elements with a DIV and doing the following allowed me to do that.
class DivBlot extends BlockEmbed { }
DivBlot.blotName = 'div';
DivBlot.tagName = 'div';
Quill.register(DivBlot);